# asynchronous web services between different platforms

Tags: vb.net, web-services, asmx, webservices-client

I am writing web services with VB.NET (2.0). The client side will use different technologies such as Java and Siebel. So, if I write asynchronous web services, is it possible for different platforms to consume them? I know it is quite easy with a consumer having .NET platform, but not sure for different platforms. Is it enough for them to have asynchronous ability, or should it be a similar platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that you are ever writing an asynchronous web service. Your call to a web service is asynchronous.  So in that case it's more of what can the caller consume.  If you create a web service that returns a type that your caller cannot consume except a certain platform, then you have created a web service that is platform dependent in it's payload response, while not in it's mechanism.  Yes, you can call a web service with anything, say, Java, but can you consume everything being send back? No you cannot.

So again, you're not creating async web services.  You're making async calls to those services and hopefully you're sending something that everyone that calls that service can use (xml, json, etc.)

Comment: You're right, actually that was what I wanted to ask about. I wanted to learn what I should do / what my constraints are when I write web services with .NET that will be consumed asynchronously by different non-.NET clients.

Answer (score 1):

ASMX web services (what you are writing with .NET 2.0) do not support any concept of asynchronous services. You'll have to be more specific about what you're talking about.

In fact, SOAP web services, in general, do not support the concept of an asynchrous service.

Answer (score 0):

Web service are not dependent on platform

[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500727/arent-web-services-platform-independent-web-service-works-in-net-2-0-proje)

Comment: Yeah, I know web services are platform independent, but you can make it platform dependent by using features only available in a specific platform. DataSet is one of them, for instance, so if your client is not using .NET, it is a bad idea to return DataSets in web services. My question about being asynchronous is similar; can a Java etc client consume an asynchronous web service written in .NET?